# Search for Substring in file, return line and position in Java

Tags: java, substring, bufferedreader

I want to write a program, which takes as input a string, searches a `java` file for the string and outputs the line(s) and the position(s) where it occurs.

My main problem is creating a "storage" for my results.
I cannot use lists, so I want to solve this with an 2 dimensional array[][]. But I can't just append a new first level element for every line and a second level element for every position the string occurs in.

I would have to know how many strings there allready are to create the array, don't I?

My main Idea: I need to read in a line via `input.readLine()` and check it with `indexOf()` if the substring is in that line. If it is, I save the positiona and continue my search until it returns -1. I continue untill `input.readLine` returns `null`.
If this concept is correct, I just need to solve the "storage" problem.

Comment: u want to just store the position?

Comment: you can always create your own class with the necessary details and then have an ArrayList of that class!

Comment: If the main aim is just to print the line position & string, then do you need to 'store' the actual value? Why not just print it out as you find a match?

Comment: Or you can even just use a HashMap, with key as line number and value as the position. Of course this will work only if you need to store just one position per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multimap.

```
    HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> lineAndPosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lineAndPosition.add(1); //line number
    lineAndPosition.add(23); //position number 
    map.put("key", lineAndPosition);
```

so each key will map to an array which will store line number and position of the occurence.